# Correct structure of related data in the API method

Tags: reactjs, api-design

Good afternoon!

I'm developing an API for a web service. I need to render the form with default data downloaded from server.

The method 'small-form' returns dictionaries of countries and cities.

Every city has an id of the country where it is located. If we need to know all cities in the country - it is necessary to iterate through all the cities.

There are two options to solve this problem:

1.Add an list of id's with all cities related to the countries.

2.Create a separate dictionary, where the keys are id's of the countries, and the values ​​are the lists of cities id's.

I can not understand how will it be more correct:

```
{
    "Countries": {
        "country id": {
            "id": "country id",
            "name": "country name",
            "citys": ["city id", "city id" ...]
        },
    },
    "Cities": {
        "city id": {
            "id": "id of the city",
            "name": "city name",
            "country__id": "country id",
        }
    }
}
```

or so:

```
{
    "Countries": {
        "country id": {
            "id": "country id",
            "name": "country name",
        },
    },
    "Cities": {
        "city id": {
            "id": "id of the city",
            "name": "city name",
            "country_id": "country id",
        }
    },
    "countries_cities":{
        "country id":["id city", "city"...]
    }
}
```